# DIV position offset to left on chrome but not firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-position

On the home page of my website [mondo-bongo.net](http://mondo-bongo.net) I have a grid setup where I've displayed rows of 3 thumbnails. Though on chrome you'll notice that the grid (div class="grid_gallery") is offset to left about 8px making it slightly sit behind my sidebar. Compared to firefox where the position is fine and lines up with my side bar on the left.

I've tried searching the forums for people with a similar issues though my very basic html/css terminology does me no favors.

Is anyone aware of why this is only happening in chrome and a possible fix.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you to add a sample of your problem using https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Why not use flex box?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the .grid-gallery class' width property to

```
width: calc(100% - 250px);
```

Seems to fix the issue, at least in Chrome/Firefox dev tools.  Give it a go and let us know if it helps!

Comment: Interestingly, it looks like Chrome calculates vw differently to Firefox.  If you set the width of the body tag to 100vw, in Chrome it's 1920px (the width of my monitor), but in Firefox it's 1903px

Comment: Looks like Firefox is including the width of the scrollbar, while Chrome is not?

Comment: Thanks very much this fixed my problem.

Comment: Cool, glad to help!  Could you please upvote my answer if it solved your problem?